# Django select изменение цены в зависимости от value

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

у меня есть выпадающий список обьемов товара и добавление в корзину,

```
                    <form action="{% url 'cart_add' product.id %}" method="GET" name="size">
                      
          <label>Выберите объем</label>

          <select name="size" class="form-control" >
            {% for prod in product.sizes.all %}
              <option name="size" value="{{prod.size}}">{{prod.size}} мл</option>
              {%endfor%}
          </select> 
          
        
          <hr class="offset-md">
          <button type="submit"  style="float: left;" class="btn btn-primary rounded"> <i class="ion-bag"></i>В корзину</button>

        </form>
```

подскажите как изменять цену в зависимости от выбора обьема и передавать это в корзину

Comment: Что конкретно вас интересует? Можете добавить код, где вы формируете цену и её выводите? Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: интересует как изменять цену jqery в зависимости от выбранного value , так чтобы выбранное value оставалось выбранным для последующего добавления в корзину,  Допустим цена товара 10 за мл  я выбираю 20 мл цена должна выводиться 20 и в select остаться на выбраном 20